# vList is Lonchar variable having 1600 record after assigning to combo-box cbo_item not displaying record

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

Defined variable vList as Lonchar which has 1600 records and then assigned the variable vList to combo-box cbo_item data's are not getting displayed in combo-box as vList is Lonchar variable having 1600 record combo-box accepting only charater datatype limit.Is there any option to create combo-box with more than 1600 records. As we can't change the widget Combo-box we want to populate the data in combo-box widget only. Please Suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @jensd on his comment about UX.

But you should get around the limitation of the combo-box by not assigning to the LIST-ITEMS property but by using the ADD-FIRST or ADD-LAST methods.

But with that amount of items, it's going to be sloooowwww

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cb AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO VIEW-AS COMBO-BOX .
DEFINE VARIABLE i  AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.

FORM cb WITH FRAME a. 

DO i = 1 TO 20000:

    cb:ADD-LAST ("1234567890") . 

END.

MESSAGE cb:NUM-ITEMS 
    VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFORMATION BUTTONS OK.
```

Answer (score 3):

Having a combobox with 1600 entries is bad!  You really should change input type. Make a small searchable browse or an input field with search options.

Selecting from 1600 possible entries in a dropdown is a horrible user experience.